# Shuffle an array of strings so that the sting must be completely shuffled and not in its original index in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, shuffle

Original Array

```
Array[]={"Car","Truck","Boat"};
```

Shuffled Array

```
Array[]={"Truck","Boat","Car"};
```

Dont want it Semi-Shuffled

like

```
Array[]={"Truck","Car","Boat"};
```

where Car and Truck are swapped but not Boat.

I read this is called **Derangement** of an array but I cant find one that helps with Strings.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's an array of strings or whatever. The shuffling is done through the indexing.

Comment: The contents of the array are irrelevant insofar as an element at x should be at some location other than x after the exchange.

Comment: Okay so I have two arrays. One is a copy of the original Array im trying to shuffle the second array or the copy so the contents of the second array are different at every index than the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution to generate derangement of an array the with `O(n)` **time** and `O(1)` **space** **complexity**.

```
String[] strArray = { "Truck", "Car", "Boat" };

String temp = strArray[0];

for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length - 1; i++) {
    strArray[i] = strArray[i + 1];
}

strArray[strArray.length - 1] = temp;

Arrays.stream(strArray).forEach((e) -> System.out.print(e + " "));
```

I just shifted every element to its left.

And here's the **output**:

```
Car Boat Truck
```

Comment: @DevilsHnd Can you pls tell me which element retained its position making it semi shuffled.

Comment: No probs. But it didn't feel like homework to me so I answered. OP may be having some actual business case.

Comment: lol nope not hw just a side project for pleasure. Thank you Shanu!

Comment: This is not shuffling.

Comment: No its derangement.

Answer (score 1):

String[] arr = { "Car", "Truck", "Boat" };

```
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```